# Use Visual studio code as an online interpreter for controlling excel and autocad

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, com

I'm intending to distribute an engine/library without user interface or with minimum. Instead, I want to produce c# text files from database and let end user edit and execute these code files.

Searching for possibilities, I found Visual studio code which can be used as on interpreter with online debugging possibilities.

No I want to add reference/dependency to existing running or new instances of excel and AutoCAD. Then end user can interact with my object model.

Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? UI-automation of excel/autoCAD? an actual code library?

Comment: Project is about some technical engineering stuff. engineers can write a little bit of code. yes, automation with a precompiled dll as the library (my code) and a bit of coding for that library by end users.